# How to build a complex Form in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

thanks for checking my question. 
I have faced a problem that I am not sure how to build a form like this one.

[image]

Except 2 rows(Total Price, Total Revenue), all rows and columns should be editable so users can put any data and based on some calculation formula , Total Price and Revenue should be calculated.

Is there any idea to build this kind of complete a Form ? 
Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that it should be implemented using Angular Forms? I don't think that it will be optimal solution. You could try something like this 
[ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-getting-started) or just create your own editable "table-component" in order to solve your task.

Comment: I hope you have solved the issue, but still, if you are looking for a good solution then please let me know, I will guide the same.